# Evento Change de Select no funciona en Onload

Tags: php, javascript

tengo la siguiente función Javascript:

```
function Ini_Form() {
      var data="";
      data= '<option value="0">Seleccione...</option>';
      data= data + '<option value="2">TRANSPORTES MARVISUR</option>';
      $("#cmbResponsable").html(data);
      $('#cmbResponsable > option[value="2"]').attr('selected','selected');
      $("#cmbResponsable").change();
  }
```

Dicha función la creo desde PHP (el contenido del Select es dinámico) y la invoco en el evento onload de la pagina, el tema es que este select(#CmbResposable) lo tengo amarrado a un select(#CmbDocumentos) que carga unos documentos de acuerdo al responsable que selecciono. por lo que necesito ejecutar el evento Change del select(#CmbResposable). de antemano gracias por su ayuda y atención.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe crear un Listener para el evento change del select, así:

```
function Ini_Form() {

    var data="";
    data= '<option value="0">Seleccione...</option>';
    data= data + '<option value="2">TRANSPORTES MARVISUR</option>';
    $("#cmbResponsable").html(data);
    $('#cmbResponsable > option[value="2"]').attr('selected','selected');
    $("#cmbResponsable").change();
    $(document).on('change', "#cmbResponsable", function (e) {
        alert("ud ha seleccionado: "+$('#cmbResponsable').val()+" "+$('#cmbResponsable option:selected').text());
    });
}

Ini_Form();
```

Como ud lo está intentando crear no funciona, porque el DOM no existe en el momento donde se ejecuta la linea  `$("#cmbResponsable").change();`, es decir, no le asigna el evento `change();` a nada, pues el elemento html `#cmbResponsable` no existe en ese momento.

[Ejemplo funcional](https://codepen.io/cvalencia/pen/ooLZLL)

Comment: funciono perfectamente gracias.